# Java, how to replace a sequence of numbers in a string

Tags: java, regex, replace, numbers

I am trying to replace any sequence of numbers in a string with the number itself within brackets. 
So the input:

```
"i ee44 a1 1222"
```

Should have as an output:

```
"i ee(44) a(1) (1222)"
```

I am trying to implement it using String.replace(a,b) but with no success.

Comment: Can you show what you tried?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
"i ee44 a1 1222".replaceAll("\\d+", "($0)");
```

Try this and see if it works.

Since you need to work with regular expressions, you may consider using `replaceAll` instead of `replace`.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `replaceAll`. This method uses two arguments

1. `regex` for substrings we want to find
2. `replacement` for what should be used to replace matched substring.

In `replacement` part you can use [groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) matched by regex via `$x` where `x` is group index. For example

```
"ab cdef".replaceAll("[a-z]([a-z])","-$1")
```

will produce new string with replaced every two lower case letters with `-` and second currently matched letter (notice that second letter is placed parenthesis so it means that it is in group 1 so I can use it in replacement part with `$1`) so result will be `-b -d-f`.

Now try to use this to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `String.replaceAll` with regular expressions:

```
"i ee44 a1 1222".replaceAll("(\\d+)", "($1)");
```